# How can I filter a firestore collection using lodash _.filter()?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, lodash, angularfire2

I am trying to filter a collection retrieved from firebase firestore (by the help of angularfire2) . The problem is that I don't get anything into the filtered list.

Here's my code:

### companies.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { Company } from '../../shared/models';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-companies',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.scss']
})

export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {

  filters = {}
  private companiesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Company>;
  companies: any;
  filteredCompanies: any;

  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.companiesCollection = afs.collection<Company>('companies');
    this.getCompanies().subscribe(() => {
            this.applyFilters();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getCompanies() {
    return this.companies = this.afs.collection<Company>('companies').valueChanges();
  }
  /// filter properties that resolve to true
  filterBoolean(property: string, rule: boolean) {
    if (!rule) this.removeFilter(property)
    else {
      this.filters[property] = val => val
      this.applyFilters()
    }
  }

  private applyFilters() {
     this.filteredCompanies = _.filter(this.companies, _.conforms(this.filters) )
  }
```

### companies.component.html

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="filterBoolean('firstCondition', $event.target.checked)"> True or false 1?
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="filterBoolean('secondCondition', $event.target.checked)"> True or false 2?
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="filterBoolean('secondCondition', $event.target.checked)"> True or false 3?
</div>


<!-- (WORKING): Displays all the companies names -->
<div *ngFor="let company of companies | async">
  <h6>{{ company.name }}</h6>
</div>

<!-- (NOT WORKING): Displays all the filtered companies -->
<div *ngFor="let filteredCompany of filteredCompanies">
  <h6>{{ filteredCompany.name }}</h6>
</div>
```

### What I'm using:

Angular 6, angularfire2 (v.5), lodash (v.4).

### Help:

Am I mismatching the data structure in some way? 
Anyone that may have a solution to this?

I'm following [this tutorial from  Jeff Delaney](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-property-data-filtering-with-firebase-and-angular-4/) and trying to adapt to firestore instead of realtime database under "Option 1 - Client Side Filtering" in the article.

Any help that can lead me closer to the goal would be much appreciated.

### Edit with solution:

DeborahK's answer helped me solve this.

Changed in the constructor to:

```
this.getCompanies().subscribe(companies => {
        this.companies = companies; // <== Added this line
        this.applyFilters();
});
```

And the function `getCompanies()` to:

```
// Now only returns the retrieved collection    
getCompanies() {
        return this.afs.collection<Company('companies').valueChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `this.companies` set? It looks like you are passing it into the filter, but not setting it anywhere.

```
this.filteredCompanies = _.filter(this.companies, _.conforms(this.filters) )
```

Note in the above code that you are using `this.companies` as the source for your filtering. If it is not set there won't be any filtered companies.

Should this code:

```
this.getCompanies().subscribe(() => {
        this.applyFilters();
});
```

Perhaps be this?

```
this.getCompanies().subscribe(companies => {
        this.companies = companies;
        this.applyFilters();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Setting this.companies in getCompanies(). The problem is not to display this.companies, that works. What I'm struggling with is to be able to display filteredCompanies that seems to be empty.

Comment: Yes, but you are *using* `this.companies` to perform the filter. If it is empty at that point so will your filtered list be empty. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, you're a hero! It worked! But I can't understand why. If you may have the time, would you like to explain why `applyFilters()` can't read `this.companies` without your solution? I mean, I applied the filter after `getCompanies()` was performed were I set `this.companies`.

However, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I don't see where in your code snippet that you set it. Could you update your question to include the code where you are setting it now and I'll see if I can explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: You should be able to scroll down in the code snippet and see the the `getCompanies()` function. Had the line `return this.companies = this.afs.collection<Company>('companies').valueChanges();` in there.

Comment: With the `valueChanges()` on the end, aren't you assigning this.companies in the above line of code to an Observable that is watching for changes to the list of companies ... not to the companies themselves?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Especially since `this.companies` is not an observable of companies and instead has a defined type as `any`. Thank you.